# Pka and buffers

Tags: acid-base

I'm currently studying pKa in my chemistry class, and the mathematical definition $(-log(ka))$ doesn't really explain it tangibly to me. Can you please try to simplify what pKa means and how is it useful when studying buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $pSomething$ is somewhat old and probably dates back to the use of logarithm tables.

The $p$ notation simply means "**Take the negative logarithm of what follows the p**".

**Example:** let the acid constant $K_a$ of some (weak) acid be $1\times 10^{-5}$, then the $pK_a$ is:

$$pK_a=-\log  K_a=-\log \big(1\times 10^{-5}\big)=5$$

$5$ is of course a more manageable number than $1\times 10^{-5}$.

That is really all there is to it. We can take a $p$ value of anything, like a solubility product, or some equilibrium constant $K$. It is particularly helpful when the $Something$ is really small ($<<1$).

So taking the $p$ value is essentially a way of converting unwieldingly small numbers into something much easier to deal with. Buffers deal with weak acids and bases, so you'll find $p$ values frequently used in that field.

Of course you can convert a $pK$ value back to its $K$ value:

$$K=10^{-pK}$$

Comment: Well this is not surprising since chemistry/physics always do this kind of things, create a whole new something just to simplify calculations. Thank you though.

Comment: Yes. Although a bit old, $pK$ values still have their uses. I still use them a lot. Upvote? :-)

Comment: OP doesn't have enough rep. to upvote you, but can accept your answer.